# How to create an Email Form that send message to target email?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

So I'm trying to create an email form for my Contact Us Page. my problem is i dont have any idea on how does this email form i have this code for my Form 
As Shown Below:

```
<form method = "post" action = "contactus.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class = "emailform">
    <input type = "text" placeholder = "Name" name = "name" style="width:450px; padding:5px;" required><br>
    <input type = "text" placeholder = "Email" name = "email" style="width:450px; padding:5px;" required><br>
    <textarea name = "message" placeholder = "Message" style = "width:450px; padding: 5px; height: 155px;" required></textarea><br>
    <button type = "submit" name = "send">Send</button>
</div>
</form>
```

it will be really helpful if someone answer 
by the way I'm only using notepad++ for editing my codes.
and im also a newbie :)

Thank you in advance

Comment: check this http://codechirps.com/php-email-contact-form-tutorial/

Comment: Please check php tutorials for sending mail. http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-send-email.php

Answer (score 0):

try this in your contactus.php page.

```
<?php


$to = "recieveraddress@mail.com";
$subject = "Your subject";
$txt = $_POST['message'];
$headers = "From: ".$_POST['email'];

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: So i did exactly what you said but i got some php errors like unidentified index: message and unidentified index: email. and also this error:

Comment: Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\Villa d El-lita\contactus.php on line 69

Comment: this mail function will work only on live servers and not in localhost.

Comment: submit the form with the values from your above form. you will not recieve undefined index errors

Comment: Oh i see thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your "contactus.php" file.And replace "your@email.com" with your email address.Please put "contactus.php" in the same directory where your form file is placed.

```
<?php
function clean($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['message']) && $_POST['name'] != '' && $_POST['email'] != '' && $_POST['message'] != '') {
    foreach($_POST as $key = > $value)
        $_POST[$key] = clean($value);

    $to = 'your@email.com';
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = 'Customer support needed';
    $message = 'Name='.$_POST['name'].'  Message='.$_POST['message']; 


    // Sending email
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message)){
        echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
    } else{
        echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\Villa d El-lita\contactus.php on line 83

Comment: i think the code works i jst need to figure out how to fix this error

Comment: Yes,This is working code.You just need to look at your server configuration.And if done, please accept this answer.